# Are there any IDA Pro alternatives?

Tags: debugging, disassembly

**Are there any disassembler which provide a feature set comparable to IDA Pro?**

I'm interested in both free and commercial products. Please use one answer per product and if possible write a short comment about it, like "easy to use", "many features", "only support for PE files", ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not to my knowledge. IDA Pro is clearly the best disassembler around. To the point that even the free (old) version of IDA (4.9) doesn't have a real challenger.

For the sakes of providing a comparison, you might want to try [PVDasm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PVDasm)

Answer (score 9):

IDA Pro is a commercial licensed product and so has the funding to put the advanced features in place like graphing of jumps. There is also free version of IDA, although I'm not sure what functionality has been removed.

A free alternative is [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/). Another is [PEBrowse Professional Interative](http://www.smidgeonsoft.prohosting.com/pebrowse-pro-interactive-debugger.html), but I haven't used this one yet.

In all honesty, IDA Pro is worth it, if you are seriously considering a debugger/reverse engineering tool. There isn't anything like it whatsoever on the market.

Hope this helps,

Dominic

Comment: Been debugging/disassembling/hacking for over 20 years, IDA is the best (and only one I paid for)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a Mac, you should consider [Hopper](http://hopperapp.com/).

Note: IDA Pro now (as of 6.0+) supports a native solution on OS X